# Find unique tuples in 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find uniques tuples within a numpy array but am unable to. Based on other SO answer I tried `np.unique` while setting the value for the axis, but it's not providing me what I'm looking for. Here's an example:

I have the following array

```
b = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0]], [[255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]])
```

I am looking for a way to tell me that it has two tuples in it: (255, 0, 0) and (0, 0, 0). Here are the results from using `np.unique`:

```
np.unique(b, axis=0)

array([[[255,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[255,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]]])


np.unique(b, axis=1)

array([[[255,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]]])

np.unique(b, axis=2)

array([[[  0, 255],
        [  0, 255]],

       [[  0, 255],
        [  0,   0]]])
```

How do I get it to return `[255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make b into a Nx3 array first.  Then use unique.

```
>>> np.unique(b.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0)
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `list` comprehension:

```
print(np.array([i for i in b if len(set(map(tuple, i))) == len(i)]))
```

Output:

```
[[[255   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
```